# Need to call shouldChangeCharactersInRange in custom UITextField AND call a view controller function notifying of update

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates, uitextfield

Hoping this is an easy one.

I have a view controller with a bunch of fields, some of which are a custom UITextField.

I NEED to have restrictions on some of the text fields (length, characters allowed, etc.) which I am able to find help with using the shouldChangeCharactrsInRange function. This involves setting the field as the delegate on initialization.

I also need to notify the view controller of a change in the field because it will use the value in the field to recalculate other fields. Presently I have the view controller as the delegate to the field. But this way I can't define my own shouldChangeCharactersInRange function.

Can anyone help me straighten this out please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the view controller not the object that imposes the data restrictions on the text field? If it isn't, what object is?

Comment: @Scott : I believe the textfield is its own delegate when he uses his custom UITextField class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` in the viewController, then check if it's called by an instance of your custom `UITextField`. If it is, call the specific `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` of your customClass.
After that, since you were in the controller in the first place, you can recalculate your other fields. Would that work ?
And you should add some code to your questions, it would be easier to explain and help with it.

Comment: I achieved what I was after by implementing this in conjunction with add an event listener on the field for the UIControlEventEditingChanged event. This will execute if the field was edited which is only true if the shouldChangeCharactersInRange function returned TRUE. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` can have different code depending on what custom textfield you are editing.

```
- (BOOL) textField: (UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange: (NSRange)range replacementString: (NSString *)string {    
  if (theTextField == textField1){    
     //do soemthing   
  }
  else if()
  {
     //something different
  }
  //etc...

  //Call self function to notify self that changetext was called
}
```

Or you could set the viewController as a weak class object inside your custom textfields and make the textfield it's own delegate.  Then inside the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` function you can call a function on the viewcontroller object.  That way is more messy and not as Apple-esque.